# Lookup word etymology in python?

Tags: python, nltk

How would you go about looking up the language of origin of an English word in Python. For example, the English word "table" comes from the Latin "tabula". How would you feed "table" to a Python script to get it to output 'latin'?

Comment: Where do you see that NLTK offers a way of getting etymology? Or are you simply saying that you can access WordNet using NLTK?

Comment: I don't know who thumbed down my answer, but scrapping is the way to programmatically "look things up".

Comment: I looked through the NLTK package and the Wordnet API and could not find any reference to etymology.

Comment: In my original question, I confused two sections of the nltk book's section on tagging. I removed the (presumably incorrect) assertion from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a scraper and a dictionary website.
Follow [This Tutorial](http://scraping.pro/python-lxml-scrape-online-dictionary/) but instead of using dictionary.com I would use [this website.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=competence) notice that you can drop in a variable in the place of competence just like they do in the tutorial.

```
doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/%s' % word)
```

goes to

```
doc = lxml.html.parse('www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=%s' % word)
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's the Etymological Wordnet (http://etym.org).
The website provides a text file containing etymological information.
You can build a database out of this and read it from Python.

The good thing about this approach is that it is offline.
(If you scrape a webpage instead, your programs stop working once they renew their website.)